# Reading contents from several files and writing to one file

Tags: c#, file-io

In my application there is a situation like this.Before creating a file, my application search for files in a directory under a particular filename. If any file/files found, then it should read each files contents and write these contents(of each file) to a new file. I have googled many and tried some like this:

```
string temp_file_format = "ScriptLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH");

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path,temp_file_format);
foreach (FileAccess finfo in files)
{
 string text = File.ReadAllText(finfo);
}
```

and

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
System.IO.FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(temp_file_format);
foreach (FileInfo finfo in files)
{
  finfo.OpenRead();
}
```

But all these failed..Can anyone show me an alternative for this?

Is there anything wrong in my temp_file_format string?

It will be nice if I could prepend these contents to the new file. Else also, no worries..

any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: What do you mean by failed? it throws error or does not read contents?

Comment: You don't need any more alternative. Just use methods correctly. For ex `File.ReadAllText` takes a string as parameter, dont cast string to `FileAccess` etc.

Comment: @Karthik:It even throws some error like: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'string' and so on..

Comment: @I4V:I used as File.ReadAllText(finfo)..Then also it throws an error: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short snippet that reads all the files and out puts them to the path `outputPath`

```
var lines = from file in  Directory.GetFiles(path,temp_file_format)
            from line in File.ReadAllLines(file)
            select line;
File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, content);
```

The problem you are having with your code is not really related to reading files but simply trying to use an object as a type it's not. `Directory.GetFiles` returns an array of `string` and `File.ReadXXX` and `File.OpenRead` expects the path as a string. So you simply need to pass each of the strings returned as the path argument to the appropriate method. The above is one such example. Hope it helps both solve your problem and explain the actually issue with your code

Comment: I think this will get the contents from only one file..right?

Comment: no it will get all the lines from all the files. It's the query comprehension version of a call to `SelectMany`

Comment: @vysakh Nope. You could just... try it (or _read the code_. with the documentation for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

Comment: @RuneFS +1 for actually telling me about `WriteAllLines` :) I had `ReadAllLines` in my answer alright :). Also, kudos for explaining the OP the problem with his attempt

Answer (score 2):

This is a compete working implementation that does all of that

- without reading everything in memory at one time (which doesn't work for large files)
- without keeping any files open for more than the required time

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program { 
    public static void Main()
    {
        var all = Directory.GetFiles("/tmp", "*.cpp")
             .SelectMany(File.ReadAllLines);

        using (var w = new StreamWriter("/tmp/output.txt"))
            foreach(var line in all)
                w.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

I tested it on mono 2.10, and it should work on any .NET 4.0+ (for `File.ReadAllLines` which is a *lazy* linewise enumerable)

Comment: @vysakh Did you add "using System.Linq;" ?

Comment: @sehe: If I have 10 files, will this read from allthose 10 files and write the same contents in my new file?

Comment: anyway to prepend the contents to a new file?

Comment: any possibility to delete all those files?

Comment: I already have one file..Actually I am appending all those contents to this file.Thats why I asked anyway to prepend?

Comment: @vysakh you can't prepend to a file. You can however treat the previous output file as the last input file when you read. That said you are probably better of reading in reverser order that trying to prepend. Reading in reverse order takes just as long whereas prepending requires you to read an additional file and hence takes longer (the overhead ever increasing with the size of the file)

Comment: @sehe:sorry sehe...But I didnt mean it to hurt you..I know your's is also right..but cant put tick mark for 2 answers..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach (FileInfo finfo in files)
{
try
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("finfo "))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var output = File.Create(outputPath))
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(InputPath,temp_file_format))
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```